# Как обратиться к базе данных из произвольного класса? Android

Tags: java, android

Вот такой вот у меня класс

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;
    private SQL_Helper mDatabaseHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mSQLiteDatabase;


    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.my_item_list, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //  return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_item_list, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ColorButton);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ArrowView);

        // Вот в этой строчке ругается!
        // не могу создать экземпляр класса, где работаю с БД
        mDatabaseHelper = new SQL_Helper(this);    

        textView.setText(values[position]);

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
        String s = values[position];
        System.out.println(s);
       return rowView;
    }

}
```

SQL_Helper.class

```
public class SQL_Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {

    public void addButton(MyButton myButton) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_BUTTON_NUMBER,myButton.getNumber());
        values.put(COLUMN_BUTTON_WIDTH, myButton.getWidth());

        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,values);
        db.close();
    }

    // Получить
    public MyButton getButton(int number) {
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
                        COLUMN_BUTTON_NUMBER, COLUMN_BUTTON_WIDTH }, COLUMN_BUTTON_NUMBER + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(number) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        MyButton myButton = new MyButton(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)),
               Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));

        return myButton;
    }



    // Получить число кнопок
    public int getButtonsCount() {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.close();

        return count;
    }

    // Обновить контакт
    public int updateButton(MyButton myButton) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_BUTTON_NUMBER, myButton.getNumber());
        values.put(COLUMN_BUTTON_WIDTH, myButton.getWidth());

        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(myButton.getID()) });
    }

    // Удалить контакт
    public void deleteButton(MyButton myButton) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(myButton.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }
    public void deleteAll() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
        db.close();
    }

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "buttons";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COLUMN_BUTTON_NUMBER = "button_number";
    public static final String COLUMN_BUTTON_WIDTH = "button_width";
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SCRIPT = "create table "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_BUTTON_NUMBER
            + " integer, " + COLUMN_BUTTON_WIDTH + " integer);";



    SQL_Helper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public SQL_Helper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    public SQL_Helper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        super(context, name, factory, version, errorHandler);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SCRIPT);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w("SQLite", "Обновляемся с версии " + oldVersion + " на версию " + newVersion);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF IT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

Как быть?

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, `ArrayAdapter` не наследует `Context`, поэтому `this` не может служить аргументом конструктора.

Во-вторых, если ваши классы `MyCustomAdapter` и `SQL_Helper` находятся в разных пакетах, класс `MyCustomAdapter` не увидит конструктор `SQL_Helper(Context), т.к. без модификатора видимости (public/protected/private) член класса виден только классам в одном с ним пакете.

В-третьих, мне не кажется хорошей идея создавать `SQL_Helper` каждый раз, когда элемент ui потребует данные от адаптера, тем более, что у вас там всякие методы про кнопки. Создайте его один раз, и передайте в адаптер в конструкторе. Хотя я не настоящий android-разработчик, может так и надо.

Update:

Дополните конструктор адаптера:

```
public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, String[] values, SQL_Helper sqlHelper ) {
    super(context, R.layout.my_item_list, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;

    this.mDatabaseHelper = sqlHelper;
    // не обязательно, можно каждый раз брать ссылку на базу
    //   через getWritableDatabase(), но раз поле есть...
    this.mSQLiteDatabase = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

В конструктор передайте существующий экземпляр SQL_Helper, если он у вас есть, или создайте там же, где адаптер (наверное, в `onCreate` у `Activity`).
Потом в `MyCustomAdapter.getView` обращайтесь к полю `mDatabaseHelper`, напр:

```
MyButton button = mDatabaseHelper.getButton(0);
```

Comment: Всё же, как мне обратиться к базе данных  из этого класса? Оба класса у меня Public.

Comment: Подскажите,  пожалуйста,  как передать его в адаптер в конструкторе? Что нужно дописать и как передать?
 public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, String[] values, SQL_Helper sqlData) {
        super(context, R.layout.my_item_list, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Что касается модификаторов видимости, то видимости класса мало, нужно еще чтобы был доступ к конструктору, поэтому для использования этого конструктора из других пакетов, нужно будет добавить модификатор `public`.

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас попробую реализовать

Comment: Dagger2 вам в помощь!